# How to sync in memory data with disk in ASP NET

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, synchronization, locking

In a ASP NET Controller i have  a service that returns a list of items.This service serves from the RAM the list to requesters.
The list can also  be altered by a special group of users , so everytime it is altered i write the changes to disk and update my RAM from disk. (Reading my own writes this way)

From a `JS` client when i alter this list , the changes are written correctly on the disk , but when i forward a second request to get my list , i am served a stale list.I need to hit F5 for the client to get the right data.

I do not understand how does the RAM cache lags behind.
You can see in my service below that i have guarded the altering method with a `lock`.I have also tried without it to no avail.

**Service**

```
     public class FileService : IADReadWrite {
                private const int SIZE = 5;
                private const string COMPUTER_FILE = @"computers.txt";

                private List<Computer> computers = new List<Computer>();
                private readonly object @filelock = new object();

                private readonly Computer[] DEFAULT_COMPUTERS_LIST = new Computer[] {
                    new Computer(id:"W-CZC81371RS",Username:"A"),
                    new Computer(id:"W-CZC81371RQ",Username:"B"),
                };

                async Task<Computers> GetComputersAsymc() {
                    if (this.computers.Count == 0) {
                        var query = await Fetch();
                        this.computers = query.ToList();
                    }

                    var result = new Computers(this.computers);

                    return result;
                }

                public async Task<bool> AddComputerAsync(Computer computer) {

                    lock (filelock) {
                        if (this.computers.Any(x => x == computer)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        this.computers.Add(computer);
                        File.WriteAllText(COMPUTER_FILE, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.computers, Formatting.Indented));
                        this.computers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Computer>>(File.ReadAllText(COMPUTER_FILE));
                    }

                    return true;

                }

   ---------------------Helpers --------------------------
                private async Task<IEnumerable<Computer>> Fetch() {
                    if (!File.Exists(COMPUTER_FILE)) {
                        WriteComputersToDisk();
                    }
                    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(COMPUTER_FILE, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
                        var raw = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(COMPUTER_FILE);
                        var comp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Computer>>(raw);
                        return comp;
                    }

                }

               private void WriteComputersToDisk() {
                    var comps = DEFAULT_COMPUTERS_LIST;
                    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comps, Formatting.Indented);
                    File.WriteAllText(COMPUTER_FILE, data);
                }
        }
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController:Controller
{ 
   MyController(IADReadWrite service)
   {
       this.service=service;
   }

   IADReadWrite service;
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<List<Computer>> GetAll()
   {
        return await service.GetComputersAsync();
   }
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task AddComputer(Computer computer)
   {
      await service.AddComputerAsync(computer);
   }
}
```

**Scenario**

```
Initial list : [0,1]
Client hits controller calling `AddComputer`  {2}
I check the file , list is now: [0,1,2]
Client hits controller calling `GetComputers` -> it returns [0,1]
I hit F5 on the browser -> GetComputers gets hit again -> it returns [0,1,2]
```

**P.S**
I have not posted the `Computer` class since it does not matter in this scenario ( It implements `IEquateable` in case you are wondering if it is failing  when i use the `==` operator.
The last 2 methods deal with the initialization of the Disk file.

Comment: Have you tried to disable response caching on that endpoint? `[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response#nostore-and-locationnone)

Comment: I have tried now.The problem is withing the service , not the endpoint.